# Why the minimum value is always output as 0 in java

Tags: java

```
public void minMaxBook() {
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        if(highPrice<books[i].price) {
            highPrice=books[i].price;
        }
        else if(minPrice>books[i].price) {
            minPrice=books[i].price;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("high = "+highPrice+" min = "+minPrice);
}
```

When the price of each book is

- 12000,9000,8500

The maximum value comes out well, but the minimum value continues to be output as 0.

Comment: What value do you initialise minPrice to?

Comment: How do you initialize `minPrice`? Should probably be initialized as `int minPrice = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`. Is that the case? It is probably initialized to `0` by default, so the `else if` condition will never be `true`.

Comment: Looks like you have not initialized `minPrice` before checking. You can set it for example to max int value `minPrice = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: I have already tried it, but 2147483647 is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things that need to be addressed:

1. Declare and initialize `minPrice` and `highPrice` accordingly.
2. Iterate over the whole array instead of just once.
3. Change the `else if` to `if`, because it could be that both min and max values are updated. Because right now, if the `highPrice` is updated, the `minPrice` is not checked.

Updated code:

```
// 1
private int minPrice = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int highPrice = 0;

public void minMaxBook() {
    for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { // 2
        if(highPrice < books[i].price) {
            highPrice = books[i].price;
        }
        if(minPrice > books[i].price) { // 3
            minPrice = books[i].price;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("high = "+highPrice+" min = "+minPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking only the first book (see `i<1`). Get length of the book array:

```
public void minMaxBook() {
    //             ╭───────────┬── HERE
    for(int i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
        if(highPrice<books[i].price) {
            highPrice=books[i].price;
        }
        else if(minPrice>books[i].price) {
            minPrice=books[i].price;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("high = "+highPrice+" min = "+minPrice);
}
```